# What prevents a humidifier tank from draining?

Tags: pressure, water, air, humidity

I have a humidifier with a tank that drains downwards (towards the ground). The tank is air tight except for when a little plunger at the bottom is depressed, which opens a small (~1cm diameter) drain. The tank itself probably holds about 4 liters.

The tank fits on top of a tray that is about 2cm tall, 30cm long, and 24cm wide. The tray has a little bump that automatically depresses the tanks plunger, which then causes the water in the tank to fill the tray until the plunger drain itself is covered, at which point the tank stops draining.

What prevents the tank from continually draining and overflowing the tray?

Would this method still work if the tank were much larger with much more water in it? If the hole were bigger? etc.

I suspect if I were to poke a hole at the top of the tank, it would drain completely, but I can't exactly test this unless I want to ruin my humidifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Air pressure prevents it. The weight of the 100km high atmosphere presses down on the tray and us all. This is more than enough to overcome gravity on a tank of water of all practical proportions.
When that little plunger lets the atmosphere in the top, this pressure now cancels that on the tray, so gravity is the remaining and dominant force. Until the plunger closes, then the air pressure inside the chamber will drop again due to a tiny further fall in water level.

Yes, if you put a hole in the top, you will be moping the floor.

Comment: thanks. so, as an extreme example, even a 50m tall x 10m diameter silo of water with a small hole in the bottom still wouldnt be affected by gravity enough to overcome the air pressure keeping the water level in the tray from rising?

Comment: Atmospheric pressure is most at sea level at about 1Kg per cm^2, so you can put a litre of water on that, 10m high. (Any width and depth you wish.)

Comment: If the hole at the bottom is too big air will force it's way in while pushing water out the same hole, though.

Comment: thanks a lot; i really appreciate it.

edit: btw im not sure what you meant about the hole at the bottom being too big. i dont quite see how that would make a difference, if you have the time to explain.

Comment: If you just have a 5x5x5m container, without a tray of water and you take the bottom off it, the water is not going to stay in. but for small hole surface tension can be enough to prevent two way flow, air in and water out.